# Garage door opener remotes suddenly open incorrect door

Tags: garage-door-opener

Both my remotes stopped working today. The wired wall button still opens the door. If I click my remote button multiple times, it opens the other garage door.

Both openers are craftsman and the one with the non-working remotes at least 10 years old, the other is over 16 years old.  The remotes have worked fine up until today.

Any clue as to what is going on? I've seen answers about interference and replacing the remotes. But, if the remote does not work, why would it now open the other door?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the make and model of the opener, and which remotes you are using with it.  It sounds like someone perhaps accidently pressed the program button on the second unit.

Comment: Remotes have batteries in them that do not last forever. Did you check / replace the batteries?

Comment: Michael, I first suspected that, but tried the second remote I have for the door and both did not work.  I was on my way to work and will have to check both tonight.  But, both remotes mysteriously opened my other garage door, kind of implying that the batteries were fine in both remotes.

Comment: Tyson, my main remote worked fine yesterday.  Only my wife and I live in our house, and neither one of us touched either garage door opener.  My remote will only open the incorrect garage door if i press the button on it multiple times - on press of the button does not open it.

Comment: Maybe a power surge or hardware glitch erased the codes. Have you tried simply re-pairing the remotes?

Comment: Isherwood, thanks for the idea - i'll try that tonight.

Comment: I had to recode my remotes every time the battery's died so If i noticed they were not opening at the end of my drive I started butting new battery's in the remotes. + isherwood

Comment: When i got home last night, the remote worked without me doing anything. The backup remote worked too.  Everything is back to normal, for now. Thanks to everyone for your suggestions.

Comment: Are these rolling-code units or the older dip-switch settable types?

Comment: Carl, one is rolling codes and one is dip switch.

Comment: You noticed a symptom and the symptom went away.  That it is an intermittent problem does not mean the problem has healed itself.  I suggest changing batteries. It is the easiest of the various suggestions above.

Answer (score -1):

Has some one changed the codes? Match the remote to the operator setting, or reset both.